# Creating dynamic view in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created an authorized view in BigQuery that is based on 10 table x.* (x1,x2.....x10) but I need data only from one of these tables as per user selection. So I want to define a view that takes an input during query and creates a view based on the input. Is there any way to implement this in BQ?
I cannot query the tables directly as the base tables (x1,x2...,x10 ) are present in other dataset and I don't have required permission on that dataset. Access is given only for the dataset containing authorized view.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not define 10 authorized views and let users query the one they need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support parametrized views, here is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=164)